# How to say something new that has been known by someone at that exact time?

Tags: conversation

I think, the title unfolds my question.

> By the way, suppose I have a bag of apples and my friend says that he
> wants some.

I have some sentences I have made to show and regarding to my question, I want to know which one is natural to answer (or probably other sentences if these three below sound awkward):

> 1. I've just found out that you like apples!
> 2. I've known that you like apples!

I reckon the first sentence above is said by someone when they discover something new but not in surprise way. This is just a guess, but I've always thought that the second is said when they tell people that they have known something since **x**.

Or perhaps,

> 3. Oh, so you like apples!

I don't feel satisfied with my sentences above. They sound unnatural to me (I don't know the reason). So, what's the natural way to say it?

Comment: You wouldn't use (2) on its own; as you say, it needs the addition of _since X_. Or you could just say 'I [already] know that you like apples.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truly, the natural response here would just be to say, "Sure, take a few!" It's not surprising if someone likes apples, so you wouldn't make a remark about it at all.

If it were a less popular food that you wouldn't expect everyone to like — for example, pickled herring — I'd say: "Oh, you like pickled herring?"

If you add the word "so", as in your number (3) it implies even more surprise - that this discovery contradicts what you believed before about this person. It's as if you're saying: "Oh, so what people told me was wrong - you do like apples!" or "Oh, so even though you said you never eat fruit, you do at least like apples!"

(1) is very awkward, you would not say it in this context. You might say 'I've just found out..." to person A if you're telling them you found out something from person B. If person A is the one who told you, they don't need this level of explanation.

(2) is not okay at all. It would be okay to say "I've known you liked apples for a long time." (I wonder if you're coming from a language like Spanish - where saber usually means "know", but in the simple past it means "realize." In English "know" can mean "realize" only in more limited circumstances - for example, "suddenly I knew what I had to do." In the past perfect like in (3), it can only mean to be aware, not to become aware.)